# Hiding Server Version Not Working

Tags: php, linux, apache, http, cloudflare

I want to hide server/PHP version details from hackers/spammers etc when they view an HTTP response etc.

```
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.6-1+Squeezy
```

I have read articles like > [ducea.com/2006/06/15/apache-tips-tricks-hide-apache-software-version/](http://ducea.com/2006/06/15/apache-tips-tricks-hide-apache-software-version/)

And others that say to add

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens ProductOnly
```

To my Apache2.conf file, which I have done at the bottom of the file as well as turning off the expose_php option in php.ini etc

```
expose_php = Off
```

However even after reloads and restarts of Apache I still see this Response Header.

I am behind Cloudflare so don't know if they have the ability to override my settings or why they would want to.

Does the position of my directives in the Apache.conf file matter?
Are there other files I need to check?

What can I do to ensure this header is hidden from probers etc.

Thanks

Comment: I'd want to hide that I'm using a dangerously insecure, unsupported for over four years version of PHP, too. I'd want to prioritize **getting rid of it** over hiding it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be honest in that you're fighting a losing battle here. You're using PHP 5.2.6, which is not only not the latest release of 5.2 (5.2.11), it's been [EOL for 4+ years](http://php.net/eol.php). It sounds like hackers are finding the header and attacking your machine. The problem is that even if you somehow remove the header **this will not make your machine more secure**. Any vulnerabilities in 5.2 are [not being patched](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/php-install-statistics.html). All you're doing is making the problem less obvious.

Cloudflare does not add server headers, nor can they change your server settings.

As to turning it off, you probably [did not edit the right file](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/disable-debian-gnu-linux-squeeze-apache-2-version-reporting-improve-security/)

> settings from `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security` will overwrite ServerSignature / ServerTokens settings set in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Very informative, many thanks,

Comment: Yup. Hackers and spammers will try 5.2 vulnerabilities on 5.6 servers, they're not picky enough to limit it to known-vulnerable servers. Upgrade is the only appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you edited the wrong php.ini file. You have to edit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and then set expose_php to 'off' in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes you are right I am on a losing battle just I have cancer and other health issues and getting someone to help me move from an old server to a new version is hard.If I had an easy way of just doing a backup of my whole server (email / DB / websites /Cron jobs/DNS) and then installing it on a new server it would be wonderful (someone must have made a guide?) I just don't want long downtime - Yes the files you mentioned were one I had to NOT the ones in the guides I read. Already turned BASH off, CGI programs, changed SSH file loc, n other measures I can do to make me safer 4 an old sys